# Dots at the top of my frames

Tags: beamer, mini-frames

I am looking for a solution at this problem, but in the all other questions I did not find an help.

How can I remove the dots at the top of my frames in a beamer presentation?

I am using the following preamble.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usepackage{pgf,pgfarrows,pgfnodes,pgfautomata,pgfheaps,pgfshade,pgfpages}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\usetheme{Dresden}

\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\AtBeginSection[\subsection*{}]{\subsection*{}}

\begin{document} 
\title{Title of my presentation}
 \author []{my name} 
\begin{frame}[label=titlepage] 
\titlepage 
\end{frame} 
\section{Introduction} 
\begin{frame} 
\frametitle{Frame title} 
... 
\end{frame} 
\section{Section 2} 
\begin{frame}
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

I thought that 
`\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}` was the correct command, but it does not work.

Thanks for all your advices!

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) as always on this site, please post a full minimal example showing the issues you have. That makes it a lot easier for others to help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Can you add a complete compilable minimal working example?

Comment: Ok, I can try. After the preamble I posted before, I have \begin{document}

\title{Title of my presentation}
\author []{my name}

\begin{frame}[label=titlepage]
  \titlepage

\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame title}
...
\end{frame}
 
\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\section{section 3}\begin{frame}\end{frame}

Comment: You just need `\usepackage{tikz}` for the first 4 packages and `pgfshade` not pgf

Comment: Please, add the code to the question rather than in comments.

Answer (score 1):

You could redefine the mini frame templates to be empty:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{Dresden}

\setbeamertemplate{mini frame}{}
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in other section}{}
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in current subsection}{}

\begin{document}
\section{test}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\section{test}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```