# How to get rid of miniframes but fix distance between parts

Tags: beamer, themes, mini-frames

I needed to get rid of the circles that compone each miniframe in each slide. There were too many and overlapping.

I managed to eliminate them by using the suggestion indicated here:

[Dots at the top of my frames](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415432/dots-at-the-top-of-my-frames/415436#415436)

and more precisely by adding the code:

```
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame}{} 

\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in other section}{}

\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in current subsection}{}
```

The result is partially what I want as it looks like this:

[image]

The problem is that I have 10 Parts and the output I would like should look like the following:

[image]

The last Part HW is missing as it seems that the length of the invisible circles is still there.

I would be extremely thankful if someone could help me.

Here is what I have in my preamble:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame}{}
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in other section}{}
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in current subsection}{}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx, subfigure}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{color, xcolor, colortbl}
\usepackage{multicol, multirow}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}   %gets rid of navigation symbols
\setbeamercovered{transparent=20}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{}  % to show overlay page numbers 
type: page number
\setbeamersize{text margin left=0.65cm, text margin right=0.65cm}
\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=red!70!black} % red bullets
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[triangle] % triangle sub-bullets
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subbody}{size=\normalsize}
```

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Can you please also add a dummy document including the section names? I don't want to retype all of them from your image.

Comment: off-topic: you don't need `\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color, xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{hyperref}` with beamer

Comment: Thank you very much @samcarter. I am really sorry I cannot solve the problem as it works perfectly on a friends' notebook with same MikTeX and TeX Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to modify the headline definition instead of setting the miniframe templates to empty, as this will vertically centre the section titles:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
%\usepackage{geometry}
%\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{fancybox}
%\usepackage{color, xcolor} 
\usepackage{colortbl}
%\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{natbib}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} %gets rid of navigation symbols
\setbeamercovered{transparent=20}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number] % to show overlay page numbers type: page number
\setbeamersize{text margin left=0.65cm, text margin right=0.65cm}
\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=red!70!black} % red bullets
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[triangle] % triangle sub-bullets
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subbody}{size=\normalsize}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
  \pgfuseshading{beamer@barshade}%
  \ifbeamer@sb@subsection%
    \vskip-9.75ex%
  \else%
    \vskip-7ex%
  \fi%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=3.5ex,dp=2.125ex]{section in head/foot}
     \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\textwidth}{}{}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \ifbeamer@sb@subsection%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ignorebg,ht=2.125ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
}%

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{title}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\section{title}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\section{title}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\section{title}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\section{title}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\section{title}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\section{title}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\section{title}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\section{title}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\section{title}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear @samcarter. You are my hero! It works perfectly fine! You made my day. Hero.

Comment: Dear @samcarter. You owe a medal.